# understand canary console.log of jquery objects or HTMLDivElemts

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log

when i print out this

```
  for ( var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        console.log("what type? --> "+elements[i]);
        console.log(elements[i]);
        console.log("scrollHeight"+elements[i].scrollHeight);
        console.log("offsetHeight"+elements[i].offsetHeight);
    }
```

and refresh my browser (canary) a couple of times, the output differs.
Even i the same refresh, the HTMLDivElements are displayed in a different way as you see in this screenshots
[image: second element expanded]

[image: first element expanded]

I really don't understand if this is a problem in the way it is displayed, or if its actually different content type. Because as you see if you expand then, it also displays different information.

Im glad for advice.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but if you think its browser issue, you can try BrowserStack.

Answer (score 0):

Browser console can display complex objects but you are discarding that feature by casting everything to string. You can check the [console API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-reference) for advanced features, but just getting rid of the concatenation operator will be a huge win:

```
console.log("what type? --> ", elements[i]);
console.log("scrollHeight", elements[i].scrollHeight);
console.log("offsetHeight", elements[i].offsetHeight);
```